# int object is not subscriptable error and list mutability error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to using functions, so I'm really stuck here with a few errors.
When I run the second function, I am getting a 'int object is not subscriptable error'

and When I run the third function, it is changing the list based on the user input as hoped for, but when the program is run again, it shows that the change is not permanent, the list is the same as before the user input change. (its also putting 'None' at the end.

Comment: you cant expect data to be magically preserved between different runs of the script, after all python interprets the file every time you try to run it

Comment: not a completely different run, when I continue to run the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all it looks like you reached a point in which you should learn classes and dictionaries , since a lot of this can be simplified if you do learn them. but if you want to keep using a list of lists to store your data here's a way to fix your second function:

this list comprehension behaves as you expect:

```
[i[products[0].index(inquiry)] for i in products[1:]]
```

as you wanted `products[1:]` is a list of the last 2 items in your `products` list, it looks like so: `[[10,30,15], [300, 400, 500]]`
thus when you iterate over this list in the first iteration `i` will be `[10,30,15]` and in the second iteration it will be `[300,400,500]`

but the other list comprehensions below it don't behave as you expect, 
when you do `products[2]` or `products[1]` you don't create a sub-list of your `products` list, you just get the list in that position, so when you do:

```
[i[products[0].index(inquiry)] for i in products[2]]
```

the list `i` will go over is `[300, 400, 500]` meaning in the first iteration `i` will be just the integer `300`

since what you want to do is iterate over a single field you should just not use list comprehension and use `products[2]` and `products[1]` directly like so :

```
def retrieve_info():  
    inquiry = input('Which product would you like information about?')
    if inquiry in products[0]:
        inquiry_2 = input('Would you like information about the quantity, price, or both?')
        if inquiry_2 == 'both':
            print([i[products[0].index(inquiry)] for i in products[1:]])
        if inquiry_2 == 'price':
            print(products[2][products[0].index(inquiry)])
        if inquiry_2 == 'quantity':
            print(products[1][products[0].index(inquiry)])
        if inquiry_2 not in ['both','price','quantity']:
            print('error')
    else:
        print('product not in inventory system')
```

as for the data storing function, it seems fine to me, try printing `products` at the start and end of the function to see if it changes